# GCP dataflow job to transfer data from pubsub (in one project) to biq query in another, implemented on terraform, doesn't read messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, streaming, pipeline, dataflow

I implement a dataflow job on terraform, using Google template Pubsub to Big Query. Pubsub is in one project, while dataflow and big query is in the other. The dataflow job is created, compute engine scales, subscriptions get created, service account has all possible permissions to run dataflow job and pubsub and service account user permissions in project where pubsub is. Pipeline API is enbled. Dataflow job is with the status running, big query tables are created, table scemas match the message schema. The only thing is that dataflow doesn't read messages from pubsub. The only thing is, maybe, when I open pipelines (within dataflow), I see nothing, also temp location specified in terraform code is not created. Service account has cloud storage admin permissions, so it's another indication that dataflow job (pipeline) just doesn't initiate the stream. Any suggestions? Maybe somebody had similar issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYUYW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j4Pd.png)

Comment: Do you have messages published in the topic? Do you see the subscription in PubSub, and do you see an increasing number of unack messages?

Comment: Yep, messages are coming to the topc. I have to add that there is another dataflow job attached with a separate subscription that transfers messages from the same topic to cloud storage (withing the project where the topic is). It's working perfectly. Yes to all of the quesions.

Comment: I wonder if the reason is that dataflow has to be created in a project where the topic is.

Comment: Can you share the parameter that you set to the template? And when you look at your subscription on PubSub, on which topic it is created? The right one or not?

Comment: Topic and input parameters for the template are: input topic, deadletter table, output table and tmp transformation bucket.

The job fails with the following error in the logs:
WrapInsertionErrors/Map into WriteSuccessfulRecords/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/StreamingWrite/BatchedStreamingWrite.ViaBundleFinalization/ParMultiDo(BatchAndInsertElements)

Comment: It turns out that it takes the message from the topic, but fails to write it to bigquery

Comment: I changed the template to PubSub Avro to Big Query and generated avro schema from the message. Will post later if the issue was resolved:)